# How to set ANTLR3 extended option -Xmaxinlinedfastates in maven configuration?

Tags: maven, antlr, antlr3

Is it possible to set the max DFA states before table used rather than inlining in the configuration of the plugin maven antlr3 like the extended option -Xmaxinlinedfastates in the command line of antlr.Tool ?

I find it for ant script but nothing with maven.

If yes, how to ?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's of any worth - I haven't found any way to do it through Maven plugin. When I need the `-X` args, I invoke Ant at `generate-sources` that runs ANTLR through `<java>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's a good idea to use the maven-antrun-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jiri Tousek.

I found an alternative to what I call a gap in the maven antlr3 plugin. Using the maven antrun plugin allowed me to solve this problem.

Here is the statement I made in pom.xml and that works for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>

                            <!-- Place any Ant task here. You can add anything you can add between 
                                <target> and </target> in a build.xml. -->

                            <java classname="org.antlr.Tool" fork="true"
                                failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="-verbose" />
                                <arg value="-Xmaxinlinedfastates"/>
                                <arg value="10"/>  <!-- Value for the exended option -Xmaxinlinedfastates -->
                                <arg path="./src/main/antlr3/*.g" />  
                            </java>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```